# Array.Contains() is always false

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, contains

I've been smashing my head against this problem for days and have tried a tons of different things. I've been all over the forums, tried everything I've seen with no luck. My issue could be that I don't have an override, but I can't figure out how to get that to work.

I want to check if an array of 5,000+ elements contains a user-entered word. The word gets entered character by character and combined into a string(guessString). And then I use .Contains() to see if that word is in an array.

*****EDIT please see screenshots for debug logs [WordArray Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04YQL.png) -- [Debug Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y0sk.png) -- [Debug With whitespace detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Lgt.png) -- [Code that doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egNmm.png)**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Linq;


public class WordAction : MonoBehaviour
{
    TMP_Text m_textComponent;
    TMP_Text m_currentSquare;
    public TMP_Text[] squareArray;

    List<string> dupKey = new List<string>();

    public string[] WordArray;
    public List<string> DictionaryList = new List<string>();
    public TextAsset file;

    [SerializeField]
    Color correctColor, wrongColor, maybeColor;

    [SerializeField]
    float colorFadeSpeed, colorFadeTime; // 2f, 1f

    public float waitTime;
    public string levelID;
    public string key;
    public AudioSource revealSFX;

    bool guess;
    string guessString;
    int guessRegulator;
    int guessCount = 1;
    int lessGuessCount; // Starts variable at value of first current row element
    int maxGuessCount;

    string[] guessStringArray = new string[1];

    void Start()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Duplicate key
        {
            dupKey.Add(key[i].ToString());
        }

        var content = file.text;
        string[] AllWords = content.Split('\n');
        WordArray = AllWords;
    }


    public void Magic()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CompareKey());
    }

    IEnumerator CompareKey()
    {
        guessRegulator++;
        GuessRegulatorFunction();

        lessGuessCount = (guessCount * 5) - 5; // Starts variable at value of first current row element
        maxGuessCount = guessCount * 5;
        guessCount++; // Moves to next row
        int k = 0; // Indexer for key[]
        int cW = 0; // Indexer for CombineWord()
        GameObject keyGO; // Keyboard GO


        for (int i = lessGuessCount; i < maxGuessCount; i++)
        {
            if (cW < 1)
            {
                CombineWord(i);

                cW++;
            }

            bool match = WordArray.Contains(guessString); // not working
            Debug.Log(match);
            if (match)
            {
                //do stuff
            }

            //compare stuff
            string guessStr = squareArray[i].text.ToString();
            string keyStr = key[k].ToString();
            bool result = guessStr == keyStr;

            if (!result && !dupKey.Contains(guessStr))
            {
                //wrong stuff
                GameObject parentGO = squareArray[i].transform.parent.gameObject; // Gets parent of SquareArray element
                Image parentImage = parentGO.GetComponent<Image>(); // Gets Image component of parent game object         
                keyGO = GameObject.Find(squareArray[i].text); // Keyboard
                Image keyParentImage = keyGO.GetComponent<Image>(); // Keyboard

                wrongColor.a = 255;
                keyParentImage.color = wrongColor;
                parentImage.color = wrongColor;
                yield return null;
            }

            if (result)
            {
                //correct stuff
                dupKey[k] = "";

                GameObject parentGO = squareArray[i].transform.parent.gameObject; // Gets parent of SquareArray element
                Image parentImage = parentGO.GetComponent<Image>(); // Gets Image component of parent game object         
                keyGO = GameObject.Find(squareArray[i].text); // Keyboard
                Image keyParentImage = keyGO.GetComponent<Image>(); // Keyboard

                correctColor.a = 255;
                keyParentImage.color = correctColor;
                parentImage.color = correctColor;
                yield return null;
            }

            if (!result && dupKey.Contains(guessStr))
            {
                //yellow stuff
                for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) // Duplicate key
                {
                    if (guessStr == dupKey[x])
                    {
                        dupKey[x] = "";
                    }
                }

                GameObject parentGO = squareArray[i].transform.parent.gameObject; // Gets parent of SquareArray element
                Image parentImage = parentGO.GetComponent<Image>(); // Gets Image component of parent game object         
                keyGO = GameObject.Find(squareArray[i].text); // Keyboard
                Image keyParentImage = keyGO.GetComponent<Image>(); // Keyboard

                maybeColor.a = 255;
                keyParentImage.color = maybeColor;
                parentImage.color = maybeColor;
                yield return null;
            }

            revealSFX.Play();
            k++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        }

        dupKey.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Duplicate key
        {
            dupKey.Add(key[i].ToString());
        }

    }

    void GuessRegulatorFunction()
    {
        guessRegulator++; // Stops multiple guess attempts

        for (int i = 0; i < (guessCount * 5); i++) // Checks if row is blank when guessing
        {
            if (squareArray[i].text == "")
            {
                guess = false;
                guessRegulator = 0; // Resets guess regulator
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                guess = true;

            }
        }

        if (guessRegulator > 1 || guess == false) // Stops multiple guess attempts
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void BackSpace()
    {
        for (int i = guessCount * 5; i > (guessCount * 5) - 6; i--)
        {
            if (squareArray[i].text != "")
            {
                squareArray[i].text = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void InputLetter()
    {
        guessRegulator = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < guessCount * 5; i++)
        {
            if (squareArray[i].text == "")
            {
                squareArray[i].text = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void CombineWord(int i)
    {
        var string1 = squareArray[i].text.ToString();
        var string2 = squareArray[i + 1].text.ToString();
        var string3 = squareArray[i + 2].text.ToString();
        var string4 = squareArray[i + 3].text.ToString();
        var string5 = squareArray[i + 4].text.ToString();

        guessString = string1 + string2 + string3 + string4 + string5;
        //Debug.Log(guessString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Right now the code you've posted doesn't demonstrate your error.

Comment: That edit just made your code even worse. We need a [mcve].

Comment: I will edit my post so it has the full code

Comment: I'd suggest that you first do some debugging. 1) is `AllWords` really populated at the time you are calling `.Contains()` on it? 2) Does `guessString` have the content you expect at the time of calling `AllWords.Contains(guessString)`? If yes to both; start with a smaller file containing e.g. five words to populate `AllWords` with to more easily identify the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed all arrays and strings contain the variables they are supposed to at the time they are called

Comment: @Gmaronde - Just a small thing - stop putting `.ToString()` on your string variables.

Comment: @Gmaronde - You need to debug your code. On your line `bool match = WordArray.Contains(guessString);` you need to ensure that `WordArray` and `guessString` both contain the data you expect. Your code is too convoluted to follow easily from the source. You really need a [mcve].

Comment: @Gmaronde - I just saw your response to Gmaronde. The fact is that your variables do NOT contain what they are supposed to be. If they did the code would work. `if` and `.Contains(...)` are very well tested in C#. Your data must be at fault.

Comment: *I need help with lines 84-89* - code blocks in stackoverflow do not contain line numbers. Please improve the reference. Even if we count the lines with a finger there isn't any guarantee that our counting would match your IDE

Comment: Yes, you need to debug this. set a breakpoint or print out what "WordArray" and "guessString" are. Make sure you know what they are by doing something like `Debug.Log("guessword is [" + guessword + "]");` so you can see whitespace.

Comment: Hi all, please check the screenshots I just linked in the OP. They show all variables contain the proper info but still dont match. I even used nvoigt's recommendation to check for whitespace.

Comment: Have you checked the `WordArray` element for whitespace as well? Furthermore, are the string lengths equal?

Comment: @AstridE. I think thats the problem! neither one is showing white space but when I just compared lengths to WordArray element is showing 1 more in length. I just used .Trim() and the Length values now line up. Now just have to figure out the best way to trim the whole array. Will report back

Comment: That was the problem. I just had to trim the entire array and bingo now its works. Thank you!! If you leave a new answer I can mark that as the Correct Answer

Comment: @Gmaronde - If you split properly you don't need to trim the array.

Comment: Glad to help you get on the right track.

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken your line of code that isn't working and copied it verbatim. I've then taken the data that you say is in the `WordArray` and `guessString` variables and set those up. Then I ran this:

```
var WordArray = new [] { "WHICH", "THERE", "THEIR", "ABOUT" };
var guessString= "THERE";
bool match = WordArray.Contains(guessString);
Console.WriteLine(match);
```

`match` comes out `True`.

Your variables do not contain the data you think they do.

It's likely that the `content` that you call `.Split('\n')` on actually contains Windows end of line markers, so a combination of `"\r\n"`. Since you only split on `'\n'` it's likely that the `'\r'` remains in your strings and hence `"THERE"` does not match `"THERE\r"`.

Try this instead:

```
.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

If your code is run on either Windows or on Linux the above line works. Just watch out for files that mix the endings.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. I had no idea of the end line markers. I greatly appreciate this!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `WordArray` is always empty. You put your file content into a *local* variable called `AllWords`.

Your word will never be found in an empty array.

Comment: Based on the current code, the OP would have a `NullReferenceException` so this doesn't explain the issue.

Comment: I just posted my full code, sorry about that, i deleted too much when I was trimming the code for this post

Comment: *i deleted too much when I was trimming the code for this post* - removing code for SO's benefit also makes a line number reference potentially useless

Comment: My apologies, it has been updated, along with Debug screenshots. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated